# BizTalk admin console firewall

Tags: sql, biztalk

I'm setting up the windows firewall on my SQL nodes.  All outbound traffic is allowed. I'm restricting the incoming traffic.

I have the correct database port open however when trying to connect through the BizTalk admin Console the connection times out.

Is there a specific set incoming firewall rules which need to be enabled on the SQL server for the BizTalk admin console to work?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database BizTalkMgmtDb through SSMS?

Comment: That is, are you able to connect from SSMS running on the BizTalk server, not on the BizTalk SQL server (in case that wasn't clear)

Comment: Yea I can connect in using ssms on a biztalk node. Is there a separate specific port that the admin console uses?

Comment: I don't believe so.  What's the exact message you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the ports for your specific database instance open are probably not enough.  Here are some additional things you should open for admin connectivity:

- If you are not using the default DB Instance you will need to open UDP in/out on port 1434 unless you specify the port number in the connections strings.
- For access to primary DTC ports, you will need TCP in/out on port 135
- For access to secondary DTC ports, you will need TCP in/out on port 50000-50200 (maybe more if your load is very high)

Good Luck!